# How do I apply a conditional format on a date column using date values from another cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements

I want the little calendar to be linked with the date column, meaning whenever there is a new row added to the date col, I want the conditional format to color the date on the calendar.

[image: example1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test for the date in your calendar being equal to the last non-blank value in column C. The custom formula would be

=datevalue(E5&"-"&$E$3&"-2021")=index($C2:$C,count($C2:$C))

applied to the range E5:K9 (I was originally going to just use max($C2:$C) instead of index, but from your test data the last entered date may not always be the latest date).

[image]

*Note:*

Datevalue may not work in all locales - this will always work for third month but you might need a lookup on month name if you want it to work for more than one month.:

```
=date(2021,3,E5)
```